# How would I slide up (open) a hidden textview/layout without pushing a view/widget down?

Tags: java, android, layout, hidden

I have an app in which a hidden linear layout is supposed to open to show a text view with user information. The button to open/close the linear layout is at the bottom of the phone screen. When I press the button, the button is forced down, out of view, to allow for the hidden layout. **What I want the UI to do** is when I press the button, the hidden layout will slide the UI contents up leaving the button where it is on the screen. And when I click the button again, the layout will close (slide down) bringing the UI back to it's original position.

I tried many of the other suggestions that have been presented on other Stackoverflow links and, in all cases, 1) the hidden layouts are coming up from the footer or header of the phone screen, 2) the button that activates the hidden layout is far enough removed from the hidden section that there is no need to fit the hidden section within two views/widgets, or 3) I just can't get the hidden layout to fully disappear (i.e. View.GONE doesn't remove the top section of the layout). Can anyone direct me to a solution that will help me slide up and down the UI in this way? The code below is for the hidden layout (see image for visual) and I have the XML files to slide up/down if there is a need to look at them. Let me know if there is a need for any additional information.

I appreciate the help!

[Image of hidden layer when layout slides open][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/le1Bc.png

```
          <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/transition_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hidden_textView_button_results"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/daily_bread_result"
                    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="100dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="32sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="Do ya see me?!?"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView_editTexts"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView_CalculateDailyBread"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is contained within a ScrollView, yes? So it sounds like you want to make the hidden layout visible and then immediately add the height of the hidden layout to the scroll position of the ScrollView.

Or you could just ditch the button entirely and simply show the value as soon as all the EditTexts are filled out. And if they're not filled out, show a message saying that info is missing.

Comment: Yes, the entire UI content is in a scroll view. Do you mean to add the change in height ( getHeight() ) to the to the top of the scroll view? I'll look that up. This is the free (with ads) version of the app. The paid version displays the results in another activity.

Comment: No, I mean use the `ScrollView#scrollTo()` method to change the vertical scrolling distance of the `ScrollView`. It will programmatically scroll the `ScrollView` by the height of the hidden layout.

Comment: Got it! I didn't even know that was a thing (I'm a relative newb to the android world). I should be good to go from here. Thanks, again, for your help!!

Comment: No problem. By the way, is this app for pizza delivery drivers or for Postmates/Grubhub drivers?

Comment: It could be... Short story? It's an app designed for people who want to know what their hourly wage would be when they include all income, deductions and time involved with their J.O.B. The user would have to know either the hourly wage OR the amount per job. This would be good for the giga workers if one of those two conditions are met. The target demographic is people who get paid by the day, servers and people who drive hours on end (I'm in Los Angeles). It's a little disheartening when you see the difference between the employer's wage and what actually is!

Comment: @Zack Got it. I was just interested because I made a similar app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_GavinGT.DeliveryTipTrackerPro_ready_for_market&hl=en_US

Comment: Way beyond the features that I have in mine! "Daily Bread, Texas Toast" edition is in the testing phase at the moment. Btw, 'Stack' is giving me the riot act about the amount of conversation happening. I'm at annulusDevelopment@gmail.com if you care to swap info. If not, I wish you all the best!!